# django-localflavor fields not showing up in Django admin models?

Tags: django, django-models, django-localflavor

I am trying to implement django-localflavors into my Django app.

I import USStateSelect & USZipCodeField at the beginning of my models.py and then include them as a field in my model along with other fields, like so:

```
from localflavor.us.forms import USStateSelect, USZipCodeField
...
Class MyModel(models.Model):
... 
     state = USStateSelect()
     zip_5 = USZipCodeField()
```

However, when I go to Django admin and try to create a new Model object, I see every other field I wrote (CharFields, etc.) EXCEPT any of the localflavor fields. They are simply not showing up at all as an input field in my Model object form. I have done migrations on my database so that is not the issue.

Am I misunderstanding how to use django-localflavor? I read in an answer to a different post that localflavor doesn't actually create input fields, only stores data... but then I've also read that it DOES let you input data. At this point I am confused. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify choices option.

Change your code a little as below:

```
from localflavor.us.forms import USStateSelect, USZipCodeField
...
Class MyModel(models.Model):
... 
     state = USStateSelect(choices=STATE_CHOICES) # add choices
     zip_5 = USZipCodeField() # no change on this line
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for are the [model fields](https://github.com/django/django-localflavor/blob/master/localflavor/us/models.py).  The form fields are used when building your own forms (usually outside the admin, such as a contact form).  Localflavor has a couple fields that should do what you need.  Note that these are essentially `CharField`s that have some extra validation to make sure the follow the desired format.